# Magento 2.2 | Add breadcrumbs to catalog product view

Tags: layout, magento2.2, breadcrumbs

How can I add breadcrumbs to the

> catalog product view

page?

I override in my theme:

> catalog_product_view.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content.top">
            <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Breadcrumbs" name="breadcrumbs" as="breadcrumbs" />  
        </referenceContainer>
        <referenceBlock name="view.addto.compare" remove="true"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

Sadly this ain't working. 
Someone knows what to do?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Magento2 by default breadcrumb works on product pages did you use any mega menu module ?

Comment: yes I use a mega menu module.

Comment: are you using  Ibnab mega menu module ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had same problem with my Magento 2 instance. Tried lot. Finally resolved it by following extension which helps me to resolve the issue which also set full category path to breadcrumb to all products.

https://github.com/harrigo/EverCrumbs

This type of issue is due to page full cache an also know issue in Magento 2 but not all time.